# Add Alert to Reactable Checkboxes

Tags: r, shiny, reactable

I have a Reactable table in a Shiny App.

I wish to limit the number of checkboxes allowed to be checked to be three. Ideally, when selecting the fourth checkbox, a small alert box would appear next to the mouse that says, "Max 3 boxes."

Here is code that limits the number of checkboxes to three:

```
# Demonstrate popover when max check boxes reached
# See: https://ijlyttle.shinyapps.io/tooltip_popover_modal/_w_8a89c681/#

library("shiny")
library("reactable")
library("bsplus")

ui <- fluidPage(
  reactableOutput("table"),
  verbatimTextOutput("table_state"),
  
  use_bs_popover() 
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$table <- renderReactable({
    reactable(
      iris,
      showPageSizeOptions = TRUE,
      selection = "multiple"
    )
  }) 
  
  output$table_state <- renderPrint({
    state <- req(getReactableState("table"))
   
    # Restrict number of checked boxes
    boxes_checked <- state[[4]]
  
    # Which boxes are checked
    print(boxes_checked)
    num_boxes_checked <- (length(boxes_checked))
    
    # Restrict number of checked boxes
    if (num_boxes_checked > 3) {
       updateReactable("table", selected = boxes_checked[1:num_boxes_checked - 1])
    }
  })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I am not sure how to tie the selection of a Reactable checkbox to an alert.

For the alert itself, I was thinking [`bsplus::bs_embed_popover`](http://ijlyttle.github.io/bsplus/articles/bsplus.html) might be applicable here but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a modal dialog:

```
# Demonstrate popover when max check boxes reached
# See: https://ijlyttle.shinyapps.io/tooltip_popover_modal/_w_8a89c681/#

library("shiny")
library("reactable")
library("bsplus")

ui <- fluidPage(
  reactableOutput("table"),
  verbatimTextOutput("table_state"),
  
  use_bs_popover() 
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$table <- renderReactable({
    reactable(
      iris,
      showPageSizeOptions = TRUE,
      selection = "multiple"
    )
  }) 
  
  output$table_state <- renderPrint({
    state <- req(getReactableState("table"))
    
    # Restrict number of checked boxes
    boxes_checked <- state[[4]]
    
    # Which boxes are checked
    print(boxes_checked)
    num_boxes_checked <- (length(boxes_checked))
    
    # Restrict number of checked boxes
    if (num_boxes_checked > 3) {
      showModal(modalDialog(
        title = "Error!",
        "Max 3 checkboxes!",
        easyClose = TRUE
      ))
      updateReactable("table", selected = boxes_checked[1:num_boxes_checked - 1])
    }
  })
  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Modals are too intrusive for me. I was hoping for something the size of the John Lennon tooltip here: http://ijlyttle.github.io/bsplus/articles/bsplus.html

Comment: OK, I see, sorry won't be able to help you on this.